# Move a byte of a 64-bit register to a 8-bit register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, cpu-registers

I literally looked around for an hour, still found nothing. I tried `mov ah, byte [rdx]` but got a segfault. The reason I can't just enter the value directly into `ah` and have to use `rdx` is that `rdx` is a parameter in a procedure I need to write. Is there perhaps an opposite of `movzx` or something of the sort? I'm probably asking a really noobish question here, but I have literally looked *everywhere* and found nothing that helps.

Comment: Consider mov ah, dl

Comment: If you want a byte other than the one in `dh` or `dl`, you have to use bit shifting instructions to extract the byte value.

Comment: @HansPassant if I use this procedure in a C program with dl as the third argument, will it know to use dl as the argument or will it try using rdx still?

Comment: @ecm can you please explain how the bit-shifting would help me solve this problem?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-promotions-in-c/

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 With bit shifting, you can shift the desired byte to the least significant byte of a register and then copy it to another register.

Comment: @HansPassant I am aware of integer promotion, but how would that work with procedure parameters?

Comment: @fuz I haven't heard of the least significant byte before, I'll just look it up and get back to you. If by least sig. byte you mean leftmost byte, I assume it already will be there, as I think when you do `mov rdx, 0xff` it puts `0xff` at the leftmost byte.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Yes, this is the least significant byte, i.e. the one with the least place value.  You can then do `mov ah, dl` as Hans Passant already recommendend.

Comment: @fuz Ah, so `dl` will access the least significant byte of `rdx` automatically? interesting.

Comment: [UPDATE] I tried out using `dl` and indeed, it works. Major thanks to everyone who helped. I also understand what @HansPassant meant when he showed integer promotion now.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Yes, `dl` is the least significant byte of `rdx`.  Please refer to the Intel Software Development Manuals on what registers an x86 processor has.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the advice.